# Angular table date range filter doesn't work

Tags: angular, date, filter

I have a table that get data from API and I'm trying to implement date range filter,
Here is my function :

```
  getDateRange(value) {
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
    // getting date from calendar
    const fromDate = formatDate( value.fromDate,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US');
    const toDate = formatDate( value.toDate,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US');
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(e => {
     formatDate( e.issue_date,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US') >= fromDate && formatDate( e.issue_date,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US') <= toDate
      console.log(formatDate( e.issue_date,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US'))
    });
    console.log(fromDate, toDate);
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
  }
```

In my console, I get all the data before as a full array (console.log(this.dataSource.data);) and after the filter row I get an empty array, someone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value in the filter function.

Whether you do (without the brackets in the filter) :

```
this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(e => (formatDate( e.issue_date,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US') >= fromDate && formatDate( e.issue_date,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US') <= toDate))
```

or (with explicit "return") :

```
this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(e => { return 
     (formatDate( e.issue_date,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US') >= fromDate && formatDate( e.issue_date,'MM/dd/yyyy','en-US') <= toDate)});
```